# Limits at infinity involving e

Tags: calculus, limits

I am working with vector functions and one of the problems has $e$ in it. I always thought that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{ax} = \infty$$ but the book says otherwise and when I went all the way back to chapter 2 there was a question:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1-e^{x}}{1+2e^x} = -\frac{1}{2}$$ How is that case? If e goes to infinity? even applying l'hospitals rule the $e^{x}$ doesnt go away what am I missing here? So you can see the two in perspective here is the problem that I am working with involving vectors:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{1-e^{-2t}}{t}$$

What am I forgetting about limits?

Comment: Come on, $e$ is not going to $\infty.$

Comment: 1) $\lim e^{ax} = \infty$ if $a > 0$.  It equals 0 if $a < 0$ and it equals 1 if $a=1$.  2) why should $e^x$ going to infinity mean $\frac{1 - e^x}{1 + 2e^x}$ can't equal -1/2?  $\lim\frac{1 - e^x}{1 + 2e^x}=\lim\frac{e^{-x} - 1}{e^{-x}+2} = -\frac 12$

Comment: Okay thank you I didnt realize that if a < 0 then it equals 0 I didnt see that in the section but that doesnt mean I didnt over look it

Comment: @K.Gibson Not being a smart ass, just pointing out the obvious: $e= 2.718...$ It's a number. It's not going to infinity.

Comment: Well, hindsight is 20-20 and we all make huge gaffes..but it should have been obvious that $e^{-x} \rightarrow 0$ and $e^0 = 1$.  Also if $e^{ax} \rightarrow \infty$ then $1/e^{ax} = e^{-ax} \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: yeah I should have just looked at a graph much easier and I would have avoided all of this

Answer (score 1):

For the first limit it'll have to depend on what the value of "a" is. If a is nonpositive, as you can see, the limit will be 0. And for the second limit, after applying L'hospitals' rule, I believe you will only have -e^x/2e^x that simplifies to -1/2, so e^x should go away.

Comment: If a is *negative* the limit is 0.  If a is zero, the limit is one.

Comment: True, and my bad.

Answer (score 1):

First off, note that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{ax}=\begin{cases}
\infty & \text{if }a>0;\\
1 & \text{if }a=0;\\
0 & \text{if }a<0.
\end{cases}
$$

Now, this has not much to do with the limit you mention. Also, as K.Gibson points out, $e$ is not the variable going to infinity ($e$ is just a constant!).

L'Hopital's rule gives

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1-e^{x}}{1+2e^{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{-e^{x}}{2e^{x}}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $a < 0$ $\lim_{x \rightarrow} e^{ax} = 0$.

If $a = 0$ $\lim_{x \rightarrow} e^{ax} = 1$.

If $a > 0$ $\lim_{x \rightarrow} e^{ax} = \infty$.

===

L'hopital:  $\lim \frac{1 - e^x}{1 + 2e^x} = \lim \frac{-e^x}{2e^x} = - \frac 12$.

Not using L'hopital: $\lim \frac{1 - e^x}{1 + 2e^x}=\lim \frac{1/e^x - 1}{1/e^x + 2}= -\frac 12$